# How to set remote path in remote development using SSH via Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-remote

For example I have this configuration:

```
Host 192.168.1.18
 HostName 192.168.1.18
 User my-user-name
 IdentityFile D:/KEY/id_rsa.pub
```

I want to use remote development using SSH in Visual Studio Code.
Using extension "Remote Development" [Remote Development using SSH](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh#_getting-started).

**How to specify remote location (path/folder) to open after connecting in VSCode?**

Answer (score 0):

As of now, Visual Studio Code does not seem to provide an option for setting the remote path for `vscode-server` hosts.

I don't know if you just wanted to skip the step of choosing a remote directory every time you connect, but I found your question while looking for a Git-related issue. In my case, **a Git repository sitting in the root of my host** was initialized/scanned every time I connected to the server.
I tried setting the following in `.vscode/settings.json`, **but neither worked**:

```
"git.autoRepositoryDetection": "openEditors"
```

or

```
"git.autoRepositoryDetection": "subFolders"
```

**What *did* work for me** was adding:

```
"git.ignoredRepositories": ["/"]
```

to `settings.json` in the remote directory I was opening after connecting to the remote machine.